# Reduce Grub Menu Items

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have done quite a bit of fiddling and reinstalling of grub. I can get my machine to boot using the first few entries, but I would like to clean up the grub menu. I have tried deleting grub.cfg and regenerating it via `update-grub`. I have also tried using `40_custom` in `/etc/grub.d`. I have tried reinstalling grub with boot repair.

I only have Xubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint 17. I'd like to eliminate all entries after the 5th one.

Update: 
I was able to remove some of the duplicate entries in 40_custom. The bottom five entries are listed in `40_custom`. (I know this because I changed them.) However, I am not sure where the top entries are coming from. Today I had created a fat32 boot partition but was doing legacy boot with grub before. I noticed too that I have two `grub.cfg` files one in `/boot/grub/` and the other in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/`.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you

[image: gparted]

[image: Grub menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following Ron's answer and looking at 40_custom a little closer, I eliminated duplicate sections of:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

(Of course there was content between the BEGIN and END comments.) This eliminated some of the duplicate entries in grub. (Those ones are actually not shown in the grub screen shot above.)

However, I should have read this article more closely to begin with.
https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/grub2-revisited
I did the following:

```
cd /etc/grub.d
sudo chmod -x 10_linux 30_os-prober 30_uefi-firmware
sudo update-grub
```

These steps eliminated the first five entries seen in the screen shot above of grub.

You may also want to do the same for `20_memtest86+` and `25_custom`.

I suppose installing grub-customizer would work also. I only like to do things manually/hands-on if possible. I feel I learn my system better that way. Customization and freedom, one of the reasons I love Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have duplicate entries in your `40_custom`, just check it once more. To remove the memtest entries, run:

> sudo chmod –x 20_memtest86+
>
> sudo update-grub

Comment: You were right, but I also updated my original question above. In 40_custom, I had duplicates of the /etc/grub.d/10_linux and /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober sections. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install Grub-customizer. Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the GRUB2/BURG settings and menu entries. In terminal do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```